# Scikit learn metric giving unexpected error

Tags: python-3.x, list, scikit-learn

I run the code below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

and I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'precision_score'
```

What is wrong with my code?

Scikit-learn==0.23.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```py
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

Instead of

```py
metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

Maybe you created a variable `metrics` some where before this code